# Woocommerce cart is gone when going to another page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have been using `WC()->cart->add_to_cart($produkt->id);` to add product to woocommerce programatically in php. And it seems to work, as when I dump the cart afterwards, the products are there. The problem is that when I refresh the page or go to another page, the cart is simply empty again! Is it a way to make my added products "stick"? I am a newcomer to using Woocommerce like this, so know I may not be doing it right? Guess there should be a method for saving the cart, but cannot find it.

Comment: Woocommerce should automatically keep the products in the cart. Have you made any changes to the Woocommerce plug-in?

Comment: No, I have not done any changes to the Woocommerce plugin. I use session_id in another plugin, but should that cause an issue?

Comment: That depends on what you're doing with the session data! :) Try deactivating the other plug-in and see if that helps.

Comment: That can be a bit difficult since all the shopping functionality is included in that plugin. Tried to disable the session in the other plugin without it working though.